# perl multiline issue: need one liner to print last match before string in file

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I have a log file like this:

```
2018-07-10 10:03:01: random text1
2018-07-10 10:03:02: random text2
2018-07-10 10:03:03: random text3
    more text
    and more
    THIS IS MATCHED STRING
2018-07-10 10:03:04: random text4
```

I want to use a perl one-liner to find the most recent timestamp before "THIS IS MATCHED STRING".

I tried this:

```
perl -0777 -nle 'print "$1\n" while m/(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d).+?THIS IS MATCHED STRING/sg'
```

But it matched the first timestamp, "2018-07-10 10:03:01" instead of the "2018-07-10 10:03:03" that I wanted.   Obviously (at least I think), I don't have a good understanding of how the greedy/lazy matching is working.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
^
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\ \d+:\d+:\d+):
(?:(?!^\d{4})[\s\S])+?
\QTHIS IS MATCHED STRING\E
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wlL8sp/1/).

Answer (score 3):

For a fairly elementary approach, which avoids an involved regex, process line by line and when a timestamp pattern is matched record it. Then as you run into pattern `THIS...` you will have had the (last) previous timestamp.

```
perl -wnE'
    $ts = $1 if /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[ ]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/; 
    say $ts // "no previous time stamp"  if /THIS IS MATCHED STRING/;
' file.txt
```

If the timestamp is captured and saved with `($ts) = /.../` then failed matches on lines without it turn it `undef`, so it may not be there when `THIS` is found. Thus it is saved from `$1` only once there is a match.

The defined-or (`//`) on `$ts` is used in case the file had no time stamps at all before `THIS`

Comment: Definitely easier to understand.   I'll keep note of that.  Thanks!

Comment: @WayneA. Welcome :)  Also note that there are often two ways about it -- either it's all done in a regex which then may end up being advanced and tricky, or with basic processing and elementary regex.